# Image Class returning empty glob() array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class for Images with a function to display them. This function is called from the HTML img src URL with the following :

```
public function GetImages ($id){

$src = glob('../../user/$id/images/*');

$url = substr($src[0], 5);

return $url; 

}
```

The HTML img tag:

`<img src ='{$this->DIR}/{$images->GetImages($id)}'/>`

The `var_dump()` result is:

**'Array() {}'**

The Notice: 
**Undefined offset: 0**

The `$id` returns the user id as value when using `print_r`

I might be asking this amateurly but rectifying me would be helpful. I would appreciate any help or guidance. 
What am I doing wrong?

TYIA

Comment: Glob return array if not exist file just return empty array ,check array

Comment: I did check the array using var_dump and print_r. The array is empty

Comment: Then $url = substr($src[0], 5) undefined offset 0

Comment: I am aware of that yes. But am I doing something wrong there? Is there a fix for this please?

Comment: Variables will not expand inside a single-quoted string, so you are globbing for a literal `$id` instead of the value that you're calling `GetImages` with [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Comment: Even with double quotes, it gives me the same error.

Comment: Stating the obvious, but have you confirmed that the files you are looking for exist at the path you specified relative to your script's location? If you `cd` into the folder your PHP script lives and run `ls ../../user/replaceWithTheUserId/images/*`, you see the images?

Comment: Yes I do. The path does exist. And there are files present.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I had moved to add a trailing cd to the relative path and use double quotes and also concatenate the variable from `$src` like the following:  `$sec = glob("../../../user/".$id."/images/*"); `